# How to update json data in postgresql database using laravel?

Tags: json, laravel, postgresql

how to change next data in database:

```
jsonData = [{"given_date": "2 1.05. 2002 year"}]
```

to

```
jsonData = [{"given_date": "21.05.2002"}]
```

Comment: try to replace date value with regex `preg_replace('/\s|[a-zA-Z]/', '', '2 1.05. 2002 year');`

Comment: did it work to u?

Answer (score 1):

#### Postgresql update with regex:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET given_date = regexp_replace(given_date, '(\s|[a-zA-Z])', '','');
```

`regexp_replace` takes the value in `given_date` and be replaced by third parameter (empty string), according to the second regular parameter (match the spaces and alphabets). The fourth parameter is option like 'g(global)', 'i(ignore case)';

[Postgresql regexp_replace reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-matching.html)

#### Laravel update with regex:

```php
\DB::table('tablename')
->where(...)
->update([
'given_date' => \DB::raw("regexp_replace(given_date, '(\s|[a-zA-Z])', '','')")
]);
```